# Trying t connect Zorro 4 in 1 to chinese drone

Tags: transmitter, transmitter-protocol

I bought a radiomaster Zorro 4 in 1, but when I try to select the Internal RX i only have few options:

- Config
- BayanRX
- DSM
- DSM_RX
- FS2A_RX
- FrSkyRX
- FrSky X
- FrSkyX2
- HoTT

I bought the 4 in 1 because I have a bunch of chinese drones, eachine e58 and cx-10, and I know for sure that the cx-10 is an option in the multi module because i saw a couple of videos in youtube showing that. But in the zorro I bought the option is not available. does anyone knows what I'm doing wrong? Is this the cc2500, maybe they sent it by mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I send an email to radiomaster for explanation and they told me that the problem is because i live in europe. Due to laws they can only flash multi tx with specific protocols

Comment: You can probably get the FCC (i.e. the 'rest of the world') version of the transmitter firmware and switch over. New Tx firmware versions are released every year or so, so flashing it is a pretty common task.